# WordPress - PHP conditional logic

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a really simple question about PHP conditional logic. I have some code where I want to load a different header file based on the post category type. The code below works:

```
if(in_category('news')) {
    get_header('tertiary');
}
elseif(in_category('events')) {
    get_header('tertiary');
}
else {
    get_header('secondary');
}
```

But when I try to simplify the code to:

```
if(in_category('news' || 'events)) {
    get_header('tertiary');
}
else {
    get_header('secondary');
}
```

The *tertiary* header file for the *events* is not loading, it is showing the *secondary* header file. I'm using similar code elsewhere in my theme and it is working with no issues. So I'm not sure why it is not working here. I'm not getting an errors in my PHP console.

Comment: Without looking up any docs on that method, are you sure thats even valid that you can throw a condition statement inside of a method call? Wouldn't it be more like in_category('news') || in_category('events')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be two ways you can do this. Check in_category individually (this will always work)

```
if(in_category('news') || in_category('events')) {
```

Or in_category can take an array, [in some versions of Wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/):

```
if(in_category(['news', 'events'])) {
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to read the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/) and instead of

```
 if(in_category('news' || 'events)) {
 ...
```

do

```
if(in_category(['news', 'events'])) {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/)

```
 if ( in_category( Array( 'news', 'events' ) ) ) {
     get_header('tertiary');
 } else {
     get_header('secondary');
 }
```